# no matching function for call to 'meetings::meetings()

Tags: c++

New to programming , but when I try to create this link list I receive an error 'no matching function for call to 'meetings::meetings()' Been through it a few times and I'm just not seeing what it causing the issue.

```
 class meetings{

 public:


   void duplicatetest (string,memberlist *&head);
   void menufn(memberlist *&head);
   void meetinginfo( memberlist *&head,string);
   string timestamp ( memberlist *&head,string);

   memberlist *&head;
   string UID;
   string timestp;
   meetings *timest;
   meetings *link;
   int meetnum;
   string dt;

 };
```

```
 void meetings::meetinginfo(memberlist *&head, string dt ){
   string meetingNum;
   memberlist *currptr;
   meetings  *meetptr , *nnmeet ,*meetcurr, *meethead;

   meethead= NULL;

   if (currptr->meetnum == 0 ) {
     meethead = new meetings; // <<<  Error appears here!
                meetingNum = currptr->UID;
     meethead->UID = meetingNum;                        
     meethead->timestp = dt;
     meetcurr=meethead;
     system ("pause");                        
   }
   else {
     nnmeet = new meetings;
     meetcurr->link= nnmeet;
     nnmeet->UID=currptr->UID;
     nnmeet->timestp = dt;
   }

   cout << "Meeting number : ";

   menufn(head);

 }
```

```
using namespace std;

#include "memberlist.h"
#include "meeting.h"
int main(){
  system("color f0");    
  memberlist *member,entermember;
  meetings menu, *meet;

  entermember.createlinklist(member);

  menu.menufn(member);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}//End of main
```

This is the other class I refer to from the meetings class

```
 class memberlist  {

  public:
  void createlinklist (memberlist *&head);
  void displaylist (memberlist *&head);
  memberlist *link;
  string name[2];
  string UID;
  int meetnum;


  };

 void memberlist::createlinklist (memberlist *&head)
 {
 ifstream fin;
 memberlist *currptr , *nnptr;

 head = NULL;


 fin.open ("members.txt");


 while (fin)
 {
       if(head==NULL)
       {
        head = new memberlist;

        fin>>head->UID >> head->name[0] >> head->name[1];
        head->meetnum = 0;
        currptr = head;           

       }

 nnptr = new memberlist;

 currptr->link = nnptr;


 fin>>nnptr->UID >> nnptr->name[0] >> nnptr->name[1];
 nnptr->meetnum = 0;
 currptr = nnptr;

 }


 currptr->link = NULL;
 currptr = NULL;


 displaylist(head);      
}

void memberlist::displaylist (memberlist *&head)
{
 //memberlist *meetptr;
 cout << " Student information " << endl;
 memberlist *currptr;
 currptr = head;
 //meetptr = meethead;



 while (currptr->link!= NULL)
 {
   cout << setw(10) << left << currptr->UID << " " << currptr->name[0] <<" " << 
           currptr->name[1] <<endl;
   currptr= currptr->link; 
 }

 }
```

Comment: You trim this down to a minimal, self contained example that reproduces the problem. The error seems incompatible with the code you're showing, but there's too much of it to be sure.

Comment: +1. Please also show the part in your code, where `meetings` gets instanciated (probably your `main()` function)

Comment: I meant to say "you *should* trim this ...", as a suggestion. Which BTW, still holds.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that data member head is defined as a reference.

```
memberlist *&head;
```

The compiler is unbale to generate the default constructor becuase it does not know how to initialize the reference. You have to define the constructor yourself.

According to the C++ Standard

> A defaulted default constructor for class X is defined as deleted if:
>   — any non-static data member with no brace-or-equal-initializer is of
>   reference type,

Also take into account that referebces can be initialized only in the ctor initializer.  For example

```
meetings::meetings( memberlist * &ptr ) : head( ptr )
{
   //  possible some additional code
}
```

Or as it is said in the quote I cited in the class definition using brace-or-equal-initializer.

Comment: This is a problem, but it's the `new meetings` giving the described error.

Comment: @chris because at that line the function is being called.

Comment: This is essentially correct but your proposed solution is broken- the `head` member will refer to the constructor argument, which will be destroyed once the constructor returns.

Comment: @DeadMG It was a typo. I uodated the example.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, Oh, sorry, I'm an idiot. I thought I saw a different constructor in there that stopped the generated default one and then spent the longest time trying to figure out what I was missing. I'll just see myself out.